# php function header() doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, redirect, header

I have a php script on a apache dedicated server. 
I've cleaned the code to test if header() works... here is the code I test :

```
<?php
header("Location : http://www.lemonde.fr/"); 
?>
```

The page loads and display a white screen, no redirection.

I think it should be a php.ini settingor a apache setting, but which one ?

Comment: A white screen is usually a sign of an fatal error. What does the error logs say?

Comment: view source ... see if you see your php code there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: do error_reporting(E_ALL); see what you get

Comment: 1) View source : nothing, empty source page

Comment: 2) do_error_reporting(E_ALL); : no error message displayed

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is changing `Location :` to `Location:` (it may be sensitive to the extra space).

Is this the only code? A WSOD is usually the sign of a PHP syntax error, but this looks clean.